# PHP echo to remain on the same line after HTML

Tags: php, html

```
(<?php _e( 'Up to', 'test' ); ?> &pound;
<?php $current_price = get_field( 'price_details_price_b', 'option' );
$exchange_rate = get_field( 'price_details_exchange_rate', 'option' );
$uk_price = ($current_price * $exchange_rate);
echo $uk_price;
?>)
```

This code outputs the echo on a new line. I don't want this to occur and I don't want the PHP to start after the pound symbol, therefore what is the solution?

I know I can do this by adding HTML comment `<!--  -->` after the pound symbol and before the PHP tag but wondered if there was a better solution?

Comment: It is more common to get the data you need first and then display it. You should omit the pound until you have the price calculated and then `echo '&pound;'.$uk_price;`

Comment: If you have newlines outside your PHP code, they will of course be output as new lines. There's nothing PHP can do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why couldn't you just do

```
   (<?php _e( 'Up to', 'test' ); ?> &pound <?php
   $current_price = get_field( 'price_details_price_b', 'option' );
```

? Or not drop out of PHP mode in the first place?

```
   (<?php _e( 'Up to', 'test' ); echo '&pound;';
   $current_price = get_field( 'price_details_price_b', 'option' );
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe do your fetching and calculating first:

```
<?php
  $current_price = get_field( 'price_details_price_b', 'option' );
  $exchange_rate = get_field( 'price_details_exchange_rate', 'option' );
  $uk_price = ($current_price * $exchange_rate);
?>
```

And then output combined, where appropriate:

```
(<?php
   _e( 'Up to', 'test' );
   echo '&pound;' . $uk_price;
?>)
```